# PHAssetResourceManager writeData Returning Error 1

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, photo, phasset

I am trying to share a `PHAssetResource` with the original file name.  This method saves the asset resource to temp directory and shares from there.  Since iOS 13, this has been giving an error:

```
let tempDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory() as NSString
let partialPath = tempDirectory.appendingPathComponent(sentAssetResource.originalFilename)
let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: partialPath)

let options = PHAssetResourceRequestOptions()
options.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true


PHAssetResourceManager.default().writeData(for: sentAssetResource, toFile: fileURL, options: options, completionHandler: { (error) in

    if (error != nil) {

        print (error?.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [fileURL],  applicationActivities: nil)

        activityViewController.completionWithItemsHandler = {
            (activity, success, items, error) in

            if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
                try? FileManager.default.removeItem(atPath: fileURL.path)
            }
        }

        self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: {


        })
    }
})
```

The error received is:

```
The operation couldn't be completed.
(PHPhotosErrorDomain error -1.)
```

What could be wrong here?

I had to switch to `PHAssetResourceManager.default().requestData`, but this shares without the proper file name.

Answer (score 3):

The method works fine on iOS 13.2 in my testing. It's possible that the method fails for you cause of a database error (the iOS Photo Library is a CoreData database and AssetResources are a separate table). Can you reproduce the issue in the simulator as well as on all test devices?

Comment: Once the asset has been present for a while, it seem to work intermittently.  However it doesn't seem to go away permanently.  Also get "Unable to make resource locally available" error instead time to time.

Comment: Most likely an iOS 13 bug. Do you see any corresponding errors in the iOS device console? I would report it to Apple.

Comment: I have reported this as a bug with Apple.  However, I am still dealing with this issue.